# Baritone or Bass? and how to extend vocal range

Tags: practice, vocal-range, exercises

I had vocal warm up and I can reach from E2-F4 tone, but am I baritone or bass? because some reference have different vocal range, for example: in reference 1 said baritone until G4 but other reference said baritone until F4. so, am I a baritone? and is it possible become tenor? if yes, how to practice? I also see in youtube but I don't know where the best practice. Thank you.

Regards,
Bobby

Comment: Whether you can sing a given pitch says less about your voice category than does *how* you can sing that pitch.  More important still is *which part of your range* you can sing in for an extended period of time ("tessitura").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are questions to ask your vocal coach.  If you are not going to bother with a vocal coach, you are not going to get into situations where the difference between being a bass or a baritone comes up.  Also extending your range obviously depends on what voice you already have.

It's like telling us the length of your legs and asking which kind of sports you should be doing.

First you need to train, then specialize.  And obviously, based on the evaluation of your trainer.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with YouTube videos! There is a lot of information on the internet and singing is something that different people experiment and feel different things when doing the same thing. Some people could say they feel like A when doing retraction, and other people can say A is not correct, they feel B. And there is a lot of misinformation specially on "how to sing high notes", "how to become a tenor", etc (clickbait videos).

Your vocal range is not the most important thing you need to focus on. You need to be able to understand all different techniques, practice them and be aware of everything that is happening on your throat. That way you can choose how to approach each note and listen to other people and how they do that, to learn from them.

In this process, your vocal range will probably extend, if your voice is untrained, and that's when you can worry about reaching a note or the other, because you will have the technique to know if you can reach it or not.